# Trouble with EventBus and Gin in Gwt 2.4

Tags: java, gwt, mvp, gwt-gin, event-bus

I'm trying to use Gin in MVP GWT 2.4. In my module, I have:

```
import com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus;
import com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus;

    @Override
      protected void configure() {
        bind(EventBus.class).to(SimpleEventBus.class).in(Singleton.class);
        ...
      }
```

The above code uses the new `com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus`. The problem comes when I want to inject the event bus in MVP Activities that implement Activity:

```
package com.google.gwt.activity.shared;

import com.google.gwt.event.shared.EventBus;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AcceptsOneWidget;

public interface Activity {

  ...

  void start(AcceptsOneWidget panel, EventBus eventBus);
}
```

`Activity` uses the deprecated `com.google.gwt.event.shared.EventBus`. How can I reconcile the two? Obviously, if I ask for the deprecated type of EventBus, then Gin will complain because I didn't specify a binding for it.

**Update**: This will allow the app to build, but now there are two different `EventBus`s, which is awful:

```
 protected void configure() {
    bind(com.google.gwt.event.shared.EventBus.class).to(
        com.google.gwt.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.class).in(Singleton.class);
    bind(EventBus.class).to(SimpleEventBus.class).in(Singleton.class);
    ...
```

Comment: One hack is to just use the deprecated version everywhere throughout my code. How bad is it to do this?

Answer (score 2):

There is a current issue logged for this: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6653

Suggested work around is unfortunately to just stick with the deprecated `EventBus` in your code for now.

Answer (score 2):

I asked a similar question: [Which GWT EventBus should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947726/which-gwt-eventbus-should-i-use)

You don't need the deprecated event bus, since it extends the WebBindery one.

Create a base Activity that your activities all extend with this code:

```
// Forward to the web.bindery EventBus instead
@Override
@Deprecated
public void start(AcceptsOneWidget panel, com.google.gwt.event.shared.EventBus eventBus) {
   start(panel, (EventBus)eventBus);
}

public abstract void start(AcceptsOneWidget panel, EventBus eventBus);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a cleaner solution is this:

```
public class GinClientModule extends AbstractGinModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(EventBus.class).to(SimpleEventBus.class).in(Singleton.class);
        ...
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public com.google.gwt.event.shared.EventBus adjustEventBus(
            EventBus busBindery) {
        return (com.google.gwt.event.shared.EventBus) busBindery;
    }

...
```

Please refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16951859/572830)

Answer (score 0):

I have found that binding both the new and old versions to the same instance helps.

```
    /*
     * bind both versions of EventBus to the same single instance of the
     * SimpleEventBus
     */
    bind(SimpleEventBus.class).in(Singleton.class);
    bind(EventBus.class).to(SimpleEventBus.class);
    bind(com.google.gwt.event.shared.EventBus.class).to(SimpleEventBus.class);
```

Now whenever your code needs an `EventBus` inject the one that the code requires and avoid the deprecation warnings.